# How to implement the following thread synchronization?

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, locking, mutex

I have a method called `Wait()` which is a perform a long running job. It's synchronous (it blocks thread until operation finished)

I would like to write a `Foo()` method which implement the following logic :

> The first thread who call Foo() method should call `Wait()` 
>   If another thread call Foo() after Wait() method has already been called once (and don't returned yet), it should wait/block until initial `Wait()` call is done.

I have written the following code but i'm not sure if it's thread safe. Maybe there is a better way.
I have also tried to implement the logic using `Monitor.Pulse()`/`Monitor.Wait()` but it was not successful.

```
void Foo()
{
    if (Monitor.TryEnter(mylock))
    {
        try
        {
            Wait();
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(mylock);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lock(mylock) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: The description of the logic is a bit hard to understand. Wait always waits until it returns. Saying so doesn't tell us under what conditions we should *make* it return. It's like saying it should wait until it's done waiting -- great, but what is it waiting for? When is it done waiting -- when *what* happens?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to invent semaphores. Just use a semaphore if that's what you need!

Comment: Should the second thread call `Wait()` once the first has returned from `Wait()` (making it the new first thread in your logic)?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz : I agree it's not clear. I should have called that Wait() method LongRunningJob(). Now it's too late.

Comment: @EricLippert : sounds the right tool for the job. Thanks.

Comment: Your requirement is ambiguous. Are you saying that a thread that calls `Foo` after some other thread's call to `Wait` has returned must not be released until `Wait` returns again? Or may it return sooner?

Comment: Is this allowed: Thread A calls `Foo`. It calls `Wait`. After `Wait` returns, thread B calls `Foo`. May thread B return without making another call to `Wait` or calling `Wait` itself? After all, the first thread did call `Wait`, and that call did return. But it called `Foo` after that return happened. What's supposed to happen in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can easily be done with semaphores, you just wait with a timeout of 0, if it fails to wait you go to the else block where you wait till it is signaled.

```
SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = ...

void Foo()
{

    try
    {
        if (_semaphore.Wait(0))
        {
            Wait();
        }
        else
        {
            _semaphore.Wait()
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        _semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

Comment: This does the wrong thing if a thread enters `Foo` while a bunch of threads are still in the process of waking up and calling `Release` from a previous return from the wait function. A new thread that called `Foo` after the wait function returns could return from `Foo` without waiting while an old thread that was still blocked can fail to be released. (This is why my code has a generation counter.)

Comment: Reading over the question, it's sufficiently ambiguous that we can't tell what it's asking for. This might meet the requirements, but it's hard to tell. I asked for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Use a shared integer to indicate the generation and a shared boolean to indicate whether a thread is blocked in `Wait` or not.

The boolean keeps track whether another thread is going to call wait. If it's `true`, then we just have to wait (releasing the monitor) until that other thread returns from wait. We know that happens because it increments the shared integer. If it's `false`, then we have to call the wait function. To let other threads (if any) know that wait returns, we increment the shared integer and pulse them.

Here's the logic:

1. Lock the monitor.
2. Check the shared boolean, if it's `true`, go to step 12.
3. Set the boolean to `true`.
4. Unlock the monitor.
5. Call the special `Wait` function.
6. Lock the monitor.
7. Increment the shared integer
8. Set the shared boolean to `false`.
9. Call `PulseAll` on the monitor
10. Unlock the monitor.
11. Return.
12. Copy the shared integer into a private integer.
13. Call `Wait` on the monitor.
14. If the shared integer is equal to the private integer, go to step 2.
15. Unlock the monitor.
16. Return.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong: the first thread will do `1234`.
How could other threads even enter method (and thus go further than 1) since monitor is still locked ?

Comment: Good catch. It's fixed now.